# Super confused: discrepancy in subject-verb agreement in "reputable" publications

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

Asked similar question before but after looking into it, my questions was not answered.

Do publications have their own rules about subject-verb agreement?

For example, I wrote: 1 in 3 U.S. adults **have** prediabetes.

But USA today and others wrote the verb **has.**
USA Today title: 1 in 3 American adults has prediabetes.
Then in the body of text they wrote: ...1 in 3 American adults **have** it...

(Link: https://www.usatoday.com/story/sponsor-story/ad-council/2018/11/14/1-3-american-adults-has-prediabetes-answer-these-6-questions-see-if-youre-risk/1998597002/)

Healthline used have, CDC used Have other has...what the heck? I'm confused.

(Healthline: https://www.healthline.com/health-news/more-than-half-of-us-adults-have-diabetes-or-prediabetes-090915)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [*One in three U.S. adults*] *has/ have prediabetes.*

The head of the bracketed NP is the plural "adults", so the simple agreement rule would suggest that the plural verb "have" is correct.

However, the verb can be singular as well as plural, the optional singular override clearly being motivated by the presence of "one", and the synonymy with "[One U.S. adult in three] has prediabetes", where only singular agreement is correct.

For those interested in the syntax, "one in three" is a DP (determinative phrase) whose head is "one", in which the PP (preposition phrase) "in three" is in post-head modifier function. The DP functions as determiner in the subject NP (noun phrase) "one in three U.S. adults", whose head word is "adults".

Comment: Thanks BillJ! Very helpful. Is that why the article I linked seems to use has and have interchangeably because either one can be used in this case? Should we keep it consistent throughout our paper? I'm excited to study more about the DPs you mentioned - thanks for pointing that out!